# Establish 'connection retry' behaviour on start-up even when Redis is not available

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

`node-redis` has fantastic functionality for handling any Redis disconnections once everything is up and running. If the Redis instance becomes unavailable, use of an appropriate `retry_strategy` means the client can be set up to try to reconnect until Redis is available again.

**Is it possible to get the client to enter this state at start-up, even if Redis is down?**

My scenario is this: I am using Redis as a primary data-store, with a fallback secondary data-store which is not Redis-based. When my application starts, if Redis is not available, attempts to retrieve data will use the secondary data-store instead.

However, when Redis does become available, I'd like my application to start using the Redis primary data-store instead. As the Redis connection did not succeed on start-up, the `retry_strategy`, which would handle this for a previously established connection, does not work.

I could write code which will retry the initial Redis connection until it is successful, but it strikes me that the functionality available out-of-the-box is already very close to what I need, if I can persuade it to come into play from start-up even though Redis is down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default a client will try reconnecting until connected. You can use the retry_strategy available in the options [object properties](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#options-object-properties) if you want to customise it. you can know when the redis is connected since it would emit an event

```
client.on("connect", function (){
});
```

you can later decide how to handle once connected

Comment: But will it try reconnecting like this even if Redis is not available from start-up?

Comment: it does say in their docs that it would keep trying to reconnect, you can test this by listening to the reconnect event mention in https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#reconnecting

Comment: try connecting to an offline server and listen to the reconnecting event to verify

Answer (score 14):

The retry_strategy can actually **return a number in milliseconds** to attempt to retry the connection after that time. If the connection is closed when your node starts up, you can simply return e.g. 5000 when the error code is NR_CLOSED or ECONNREFUSED to have it retry after 5 seconds.

Example:

```
const retry_strategy = function(options) {
    if (options.error && (options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED' || options.error.code === 'NR_CLOSED')) {
        // Try reconnecting after 5 seconds
        console.error('The server refused the connection. Retrying connection...');
        return 5000;
    }
    if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
        // End reconnecting after a specific timeout and flush all commands with an individual error
        return new Error('Retry time exhausted');
    }
    if (options.attempt > 50) {
        // End reconnecting with built in error
        return undefined;
    }
    // reconnect after
    return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
}
```

And create the client with this retry strategy:

```
const client = redis.createClient({retry_strategy: retry_strategy});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the reconnectStrategy inside the socket section in client options.
In the below example using Exponential backoff

```
 const maxConnectRetry = 10
 const minConnectDelay = 100; // Milliseconds
 const maxConnectDelay = 60000; // Milliseconds
 
 const client = redisObj.createClient({
    socket: {
        host: host,
        port: port,
        connectTimeout: 5000,
        reconnectStrategy: (retries) => {
            if (retries > maxConnectRetry) {
                console.log("Too many retries on REDIS. Connection Terminated");
                return new Error("Too many retries.");
            } else {
                const wait = Math.min(minConnectDelay * Math.pow(2, retries), maxConnectDelay);
                console.log("waiting", wait, "milliseconds");
                return wait;
            }
        }
    },
    database: dbIndex
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per v4 [documentation](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md#reconnect-strategy), we can utilize the `socket.reconnectStrategy` and `client.on("error")` event.

```
// redisClient.js
const redis = require('redis');

const maxRetries = 100; // Number of times to try for reconnecting
const retryDelay = 10000; // Milliseconds

const redisConfig = {
  url: `redis://default:${password}@${host}:6379`,
  socket: {
    reconnectStrategy: (retries) => {
      if (retries > maxRetries) {
        return undefined; // Connection terminates
      }
      console.log(`Retrying redis connection - ${retries}`);
      return retryDelay;
    },
  },
};

const redisClient = redis.createClient(redisConfig);
let isConnectionSuccess = false;

redisClient.on('connect', () => {
  isConnectionSuccess = true;
  console.log('Connected to Redis');
});

redisClient.on('error', async (e) => {
  isConnectionSuccess = false;
  console.log('Redis error: ', JSON.stringify(e, null, 2));
});

redisClient.connect();

const isClientAvailable = () => {
  return isConnectionSuccess;
};

module.exports = { redisClient, isClientAvailable };
```

You can check if `isClientAvailable()` and then return `null`.

```
// cache.js
const { redisClient, isClientAvailable } = require('./redisClient');

const getKey = async (key) => {
  if (!isClientAvailable()) return null;
  const data = await redisClient.get(key);
  return JSON.parse(data);
};
```

Here, the server will try to connect to the redis-server if available. Otherwise, it will fallback to the secondary data store.

`on.("error")` event retries to connect to redis-server again and again in the given delay(`retryDelay`) until `maxRetries` exceeds.